# Search the index of an ajax request element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax response with data extracted from a sql query. It has this structure:

```
Response
   id:"id"
   titulo:"title"
   url:"url"
```

What I am trying to do is to find the position within the ajax response where a given unique id is.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'select.php',
    type: 'get',
    data: {
        "id": id
    },
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.indexOf(27188964));
    }
});
```

The second log prints `-1`, knowing that the number should be at the first position.

EDIT:
 I need the position in order to start moving through the array by increasing 'index'
 `response[index].url`

Comment: what does it mean response index ?

Comment: can you please paste the response?

Comment: indexOf usually returns -1 when there are no results for the search term.

Comment: The position within the ajax response.

Comment: Can you show the result of `console.log(response);` please?

Comment: The response has hundreds of objects, so its difficult to post it here, but the structure is the one i have posted.

Comment: But, it is an array of Objects?

Comment: Yes, it is, and the Id i am looking for is inside one of those objects.

Comment: so you don't want the literal index position (as if it was a string)? You want to return the object which has that id?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for, @ADyson

Comment: I think Yosvel has answered correctly (got there before me!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your response is an array of objects you can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'select.php',
    type: 'get',
    data: {
        "id": id
    },
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function(response) {
        var resultIndex;
        var result = response.filter(function(obj, index) {
            if (obj.id === '27188964') {
                resultIndex = index;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });

        console.log('resultIndex:', resultIndex);
        console.log('result:', result);
    }
});
```

Comment: It is a good answer, but not complete, I still need the position within the response array.

Comment: @cargide Can you post your response please?

Comment: @cargide Updated the answer to proper get `resultIndex` and `result` object

Comment: result: [Object]0:Object
   id: "27188964"
   titulo: "Un Hombre de Altura"
   url: "url"
   proto__: Object
length: 1__proto__: Array[0]


That but with 380 objects.